# Cant install AWS Session Manager plugin on Linux ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, yum, aws-session-manager

Im trying to install AWS Session Manager plugin on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 environment.
But keep getting following error when I use the yum command with rpm file :

```
sudo yum install -y session-manager-plugin.rpm


Setting up Install Process
Examining session-manager-plugin.rpm: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
Marking session-manager-plugin.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package session-manager-plugin.x86_64 0:1.2.279.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6()(64bit) for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64 (/session-manager-plugin)
       Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64 (/session-manager-plugin)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64 (/session-manager-plugin)
       Requires: libc.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64 (/session-manager-plugin)
       Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64 (/session-manager-plugin)
       Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: session-manager-plugin-1.2.279.0-1.x86_64 (/session-manager-plugin)
       Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Even if I try to install these missing packages it didn't work.

AWS CLI version -> `aws-cli/1.20.49`.
Python version -> `Python 3.5.2`.

I changed the `/usr/bin/yum` file's `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2` as well.

Comment: Any luck on that? Have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Yum is not the right tool for debian based distros (in this case, Ubuntu)

Go to the official site:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html

And scroll down until "Install the Session Manager plugin on Ubuntu Server" section.